# How to parse string in Ada with whitespaces

Tags: ada, gnat

I am getting input from user using `Get_Line`,
String can be a command followed by a value (command --- one or more white spaces --- value -- new line)like,

```
CMD  4
CMD 6
CMD        10
```

How can i parse command and value in individual variables ?

so far i can parse string before spaces as, but after space how can i get value and convert it in integer ?

```
        for I in ip'Range loop
            if ip(I) = ' ' or ip(I) = HT then
                Put_Line(CMD);
                Put_Line(Integer'Image(Index));
            else
                CMD(I) := ip(I);
                Index := Index+1;
            end if;
        end loop;
```

--

Thanks

Comment: Hint: Research Regular Expressions.

Comment: @NWS -- While RegEx works for this particular problem, I cannot in good conscience recommend it. As a maintenance programmer, RegEx is a constant source of pain: far too brittle, and often used when inappropriate (e.g. "parsing" CSV).

Comment: @Shark8 Good points about the downsides of regex, however we have very little to go on regarding its actual appropriateness for OPs Question.

Answer (score 2):

```
with Ada.Text_IO;

procedure Simple_Command_Parser_1 is
   type Commands is (CMD);
   type Values is range 4 .. 10;

   package Command_Text_IO is new Ada.Text_IO.Enumeration_IO (Commands);
   package Value_Text_IO   is new Ada.Text_IO.Integer_IO     (Values);

   Command : Commands;
   Value   : Values;
begin
   loop
      Command_Text_IO.Get (Command);
      Value_Text_IO.Get   (Value);
      Ada.Text_IO.Skip_Line;
   end loop;
end Simple_Command_Parser_1;
```